Prevent Default is not working in p-tabView
I'm using PrimeNG's p-tabView in my Angular application to manage multiple tabs. I want to prevent the tab from changing under certain conditions. I tried using the preventDefault method in the onChange event, but it doesn't seem to work.
My aim is simple to prevent the tab change by any means I also tried to modify the active tab index to the same index in the onChange event however It will reload the component.
ts:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  onTabChange(event: any) {
    // Some condition to prevent tab change
    if (someCondition) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}


Html:

<p-tabView (onChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1">
    Content of Tab 1
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Tab 2">
    Content of Tab 2
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>


I want to stop the p-tabView tab to change in a certain condition

You can disable tab panels (which will stop the p-tabView tab to change) under certain condition:
<p-tabPanel [disabled]="isDisabled" header="Header I">
    ...
</p-tabPanel>

I created a STACKBLITZ to demonstrate it. Check / uncheck the checkbox to see it in action.
